# Converting a wstring to jstring on Linux

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, widestring

I'm having problems converting a wstring to jstring in unix, as the size of wchar_t on linux in 4 bytes (not 2 bytes like windows and thus I cannot use the casting of a wchar_t to a jchar).

Can anyone please help me with that?

Thanks,
Reza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use something like `iconv()`, because C++ wide strings have an opaque (read: unknown) encoding, while Java expects UTF16. Try this:

```
#include <iconv.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::u16string convert(std::wstring s)
{
  iconv_t cd = iconv_open("UTF-16BE", "WCHAR_T");

  if (cd == iconv_t(-1))
  {
    std::cout << "Error while initializing iconv: " << errno << std::endl;
    iconv_close(cd);
    return std::u16string();
  }

  std::size_t n = s.length() * 2 + 1; // Each character might use up to two CUs.
  const std::size_t norig = n;
  std::size_t m = s.length() * sizeof(std::wstring::value_type);

  std::vector<char16_t> obuf(n);
  char * outbuf = reinterpret_cast<char*>(obuf.data());
  const char * inbuf = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&s[0]);

  const std::size_t ir = iconv(cd, const_cast<char**>(&inbuf), &m, &outbuf, &n);

  if (ir == std::size_t(-1))
  {
    std::cout << "Error while converting with iconv(): " << errno << ":" << EINVAL << ", left " << m
              << ", written " << std::dec << norig - n << " bytes." << std::endl;
    iconv_close(cd);
    return std::u16string();
  }

  iconv_close(cd);

  return std::u16string(obuf.data(), (norig - n)/sizeof(std::u16string::value_type));
}
```

If you don't have `char16_t` and `std::u16string`, you can use `uint16_t` as the basic character type and `std::basic_string<uint16_t>` or `std::vector<uint16_t>` as the resulting container.

Comment: Thanks. So this method is converting a wstring to a utf16 string, right? Then, how should I create a jstring out of this wstring?

Comment: @RezaPlusPlus: The *input* is an opaque C++ wide string, and the *output* of this function is a well-defined UTF-16BE string. I don't know what jstrings are, but you ought to be able to pass a pointer to the first element of the result to the jstring in one way or another.

Comment: BTW, is std::u16string standard STL?

Comment: @RezaPlusPlus: There's no such thing as "standard STL"; "STL" is a historical artefact from 1994 :-) `u16string` is part of the C++11 standard. If you don't have support for that, you can use a vector of `uint16_t`s instead, as I suggest in the final paragraph.

Comment: Thanks and sorry that I missed the last paragraph.