# convert to jstring from std::wstring

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, wstring

I'm trying to convert a wstring from my cpp code to jstring.

I know there's a method named NewStringUTF to get jstring from std::string (after getting the const char* from that string of course).

is there a way I can do the same if the input is std::wstring without using iconv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a wstring to jstring on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272512/converting-a-wstring-to-jstring-on-linux)

Comment: the other solution is using iconv, i'm searching for a solution without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNI has [NewString(JNIEnv * , const jchar * ,
jsize)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewString) function. If your `std::wstring::c_str()` returns a pointer compatible with **jchar*** (this depends on your platform), you can try this function. Note that if your **wchar_t** is 32 bit (as on Linux), you cannot use it directly. See *[Android JNI - Reliable way to convert jstring to wchar_t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122109/192373)* and *[How do I convert jstring to wchar_t *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042)* for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The easy form is to convert your std::wstring to std::string to use the NewStringUTF.

Here you have a thread with the conversion
[How to convert wstring into string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string)